# error mounting partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have a Samsung laptop which received a bump yesterday. After that, the system doesn't load the Windows (Vista), the screen remains black, doesn't boot.

I burn a LiveCD with Ubuntu to try to back up my data, but was unsuccessful. My hard drive has two partitions: the main (C:) which has Windows and all my documents, and one another (D:) which I have some documents and files. This partition (D:) is right, I can mount it. I did a back up that files were there, really I want to recover 2 folders (30 mb, no more).

But I really want to do back up some folders which are in C: partition, but when a I try to mount I receive the message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu/C06E17086E16F6BE: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2"   "/media/ubuntu/C06E17086E16F6BE"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error  
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error  
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware.
```

In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.

and now, I do not know how to proceed.

Please, does somebody know how to do?

Comment: I think the answer to this question might be what you're looking for http://superuser.com/questions/193899/how-to-run-chkdsk-if-i-cant-boot-to-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk you have got damaged.

1. You can try to save the data from it by running `fsck` on the partition (according to your post this would be `ntfsfix /dev/sda2`, with `ntfsfix` being the "`fsck` for Windows").
2. Answer any question that appears (you most probably need to accept / press <kbd>Enter</kbd> everywhere).
3. After this mount it as you wanted the first time, and pray that your files will be intact.

Comment: Hello,

I wento to the terminal, and I have writen:

sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2

the message given was:

Mounting volume..Ok Proccessing of SMFT and SMFTMirr completed successfully Checking the alternate boot sector..OK NTFS volume version is 3.1 NTFS partition /dev/sda2 was proccessed successfully

I didn't accept any questions....Now what can I do? I came back to the Ubuntu desktop and tried to open the partition and showed the same error. Do I have to restore before the laptop?

Thanks you for your reply

Comment: I'm afraid that this indicates that your disk became unusable. Also you might want to wait with accepting an answer and see if it actually helps before an accept.