# Why am i unable to mount my partition? Is it fakeraid or corrupted or what?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

This is error i see when try to mount my "Movies" partition

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda2: Command-line `mount "/media/Movies"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 1024  usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 1  data: 41790  usn: 2105: Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xd7ee3409  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 36282  usa_count: 2539: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x778fd979  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 56204  usa_count: 9512: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xc6125f51  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 38412  usa_count: 32005: Invalid argument
$MFTMirr error: Incomplete multi sector transfer detected in '$MFT'.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

---

Please help me if you are able to see the reason behind this error. I am new to Linux and don't have any clue about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error mounting partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/249066/error-mounting-partition) Probably your disk is damaged.

Comment: "I am new to linux" but this is a Windows problem ;-)  Do this please "In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice. "